# How to pass variables from controller to custom action filter in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

please I need to be assisted to figure out any issues with my code trying to deal with the above issue. 
I wrote the code earlier and it has been working but today i tried it and it doesnt seem to be recognising the viewdata value anymore. I'm sure I must have done something wrong somewhere which I have not been able to figure out myself.

This is the controller action code

```
  // POST: StaffMembers/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [PsAuditLog(AuditRecordType = 1)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(StaffMemberViewModel staff, params string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ----unnecessary codes removed for brevity----

                ViewData["ModificationType"] = 1;
                ViewData["auditLogInitVals"] = "";
                ViewData["auditLogFinVals"] = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(StaffMember);
                ViewData["recordId"] = StaffMember.Id;
                TempData["msg"] = "Registration successfull. Login password has been sent to the newly created user's email supplied in the registration";
                return RedirectToAction("View", new { id = StaffMember.Id });
            }
```

--------unnecessary code removed for brevity------

and the code at the filter context as below

```
 /// <summary>
/// Used to handle audit trail logs
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filterContext">
/// The endpoint being accessed for the action
/// </param>
public class PsAuditLogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int AuditRecordType { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;


        var userId = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        //var logRecord = filterContext.Controller.ViewData["logRecord"] as dynamic;
        var initialValues = filterContext.Controller.ViewData["auditLogInitVals"] != null ? filterContext.Controller.ViewData["auditLogInitVals"] : null;
        var finalValues = filterContext.Controller.ViewData["auditLogFinVals"] != null ? filterContext.Controller.ViewData["auditLogFinVals"] : null;

        RecordModification modif = new RecordModification();
        modif.AuditRecordTypeId = AuditRecordType;
        modif.ModificationTime = DateTime.Now;
        modif.IPAddress = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? request.UserHostAddress;
        modif.UrlAccessed = request.RawUrl;
        modif.ApplicationUserId = userId ?? "Anonymous User";
        modif.SessionId = DateTime.Now.ToString() + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
        modif.UserAgent = request.Browser.Browser + " :: " + request.Browser.Version;
        **modif.ModificationType = (ModificationType)filterContext.Controller.ViewData["ModificationType"];**
        modif.RecordId = filterContext.Controller.ViewData["recordId"].ToString();
        modif.FinalValues = Json.Encode(finalValues);
        modif.InitialValues = Json.Encode(initialValues);

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        db.RecordModifications.Add(modif);
        db.SaveChanges();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

}

However, the line asterisked throws the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 89:             modif.SessionId = DateTime.Now.ToString() +
>   HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID; Line 90:
>   modif.UserAgent = request.Browser.Browser + " :: " +
>   request.Browser.Version; Line 91:             modif.ModificationType =
>   (ModificationType)filterContext.Controller.TempData["ModificationType"];
>   Line 92:             modif.RecordId =
>   filterContext.Controller.TempData["recordId"].ToString(); Line 93:
>   modif.FinalValues = Json.Encode(finalValues);

Please I need to be guided to resolving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have `ViewData` in your sample code, and `TempData` in exception trace ?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to TempData just to see if that would make any difference but it didn't and I changed it back. But that trace is the one generated at the time time I changed it. However, same is what I get even with ViewData

Comment: Well, you may have some problem mixing an async actionResult and a sync filter : see here, maybe :https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/478983